# Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

Tags: reactjs, graph, apollo

The application uses **apollo server and react** in the frontend. In the backend I use **apollo server**. The request works via the **Playground and Postman** and I don't get any errors. Queries in the frontend **without** **parameters** also **work** perfectly. When I make a **mutation** in the frontend, I get the following error error: **Response not successful: Received status code 400**. When print debugging in the backend, I also don't get any args. In the Web-console: The XHR POST http://localhost:4000/ contains the following request: {"variables":{},"query":"mutation ($title: String!, $dotColor: String!) {\n  newStack(title: $title, dotColor: $dotColor) {\n    stackID\n    title\n    dotColor\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}

**src/queries/queries.js**

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

[...]

const newStackMutation = gql`
  mutation($title: String!, $dotColor: String!) {
    newStack(title: $title, dotColor: $dotColor) {
      stackID
      title
      dotColor
    }
  }
`;

[...]

export {[...], newStackMutation};
```

**src/components/NewStack.js**

```
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { newStackMutation } from "../queries/queries";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function NewStack() {
  const [newStack] = useMutation(newStackMutation);
  const handleNewStackSubmit = (e) => {
    //newStack({variables}); actually I would pass the variables from the setState here
    newStack({ title: "Test", dotColor: "red" });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleNewStackSubmit}>
      [...]
          <button type="submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is the mutation type in your type definitions? should look like the query type definition but for mutations

Comment: Sure, as I said, it works with postman and the playground. So in the backend everything "works" as far as I know. The problem must be in the frontend

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with the code snippets you have posted, the only other thing I could think of, would be something wrong with the configuration like if the uri to the hosted graphql server is correct in the frontend

Comment: `Client 
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  uri: "http://localhost:4000",
});
Backend
const server = new ApolloServer({
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  },
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: true,
  context: (ctx) => ctx,
});`

Comment: I know now where the problem is but don't know how to solve it. So the apollo client sends that: `mutation ($title: String!, $dotColor: String!) {\n  newStack(title: $title, dotColor: $dotColor)` as response, that means apollo client don't replac the $-sign with the passed variables. never had anything like that before

Comment: the `$` should be fine since its in the `gql` syntax.

there may be more hidden errors we havent seen. 

try adding additional error logging mentioned here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/#network-errors

Comment: Got following error: [Network error]: TypeError: forward is not a function

Comment: This might be the order of the links, I think errorLink cannot be first, otherwise it throws that error but check out the answer I provided before we dive deeper into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, you know what its probably because you need to add the name of the mutation

```
const newStackMutation = gql`
  mutation newStack($title: String!, $dotColor: String!) {
    newStack(title: $title, dotColor: $dotColor) {
      stackID
      title
      dotColor
    }
  }
`;// Notice the `newStack` next to `mutation`, that should work
```

Also this

```
newStack({variables: { title: "Test", dotColor: "red" }});
```

Comment: At the client I added:
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: ApolloLink.from([link, new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:4000' })]),
});
Now I get following error
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$title" of required type "String!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined App.js:12
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$dotColor" of required type "String!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

If seeing whole code helps: https://github.com/heitzlki/FlexNote/tree/main/client/src

Comment: https://github.com/heitzlki/FlexNote/blob/e21e7d3a7e17abaa308f232a7cb305c328e5ad11/backend/graphql/typeDefs.js#L25
`title` and `dotColor` are optional in the type defintion

Comment: try setting both the type definition of the mutation and the query of the mutation, types to either required or not and see if that works

Comment: now I can send data to the backend and can console.log the args but the are empyt {}

Comment: https://github.com/heitzlki/FlexNote/blob/cccf29108f4aec23cabf9a61f4ace6a8c9bd34df/client/src/components/NewStack.js#L29

Syntax is incorrect for providing variables, it should look like this `newStack({variables: { title: 'Test', dotColor: 'red' }});` . im disappointed that I didnt noticed this earlier >.>